# Do we need to purchase a plan to go-live DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

I have used docusign embedded signing in my application.I have submitted my developer account docusign app for review and it is passed. I created free account in account.docusign.com with same email id as developer account. I selected the app for go-live and they asked me to login to production account and I logged in. But after that it was showing infinite loading symbol and nothing is happening. Why? Do we need to purchase any plan in production for going for live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any production account. That account just holds your integration key, it does not have to be used for anything else, which means you don't have to purchase envelopes etc.
If you are an ISV - you can get a free partner account. Check out information about this here - https://developers.docusign.com/partner/integration-guide/getting-started-isv/

**Update:** the issue has been resolved, the problem you encountered should now be fixed.

Comment: But in https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/ it saying we have to purchase plan - step2

Comment: You are correct, we need to update this graphics, good catch! You may not have to purchase one if you are an ISV or use a free one. I'll make sure we update this.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Three days I was tring , everytime infinte loading symbol showing for go to live process.

Comment: I'll post here when the bug is fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh ok. Please inform. Thanks.

Comment: This is fixed now @PhpTech, please give it another try and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks.I will try.

Comment: I am getting this error now when I tried to go-live. I have free account in account.docusing.com (production). Error is "These accounts don't support API integrations. Select a different production account to continue. "

Comment: Some accounts are not eligible in production. You may have to purchase an account, or talk to customer support about enabling this account.